# Using CSS box-shadow for pulse animation eats considerable CPU

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, box-shadow

There was a requirement of showing a pulse animation over a label so as to highlight outstanding notifications. 
I came across [this](https://codepen.io/olam/pen/zcqea) while researching online and have implemented the same. It works well, however, when the label is pulsing, the CPU usage is at a constant 50% while normally there is hardly anything. 
I would like to understand what or why this is happening, and if possible, a fix.

**CSS:**

```
.pulse {
   /*margin:100px;*/
   display: block;
   /*width: 22px;*/
   /*height: 22px;*/
   /*border-radius: 100%;*/
   background: #cca92c;
   cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
   animation: pulse 2s infinite;
 }

 .pulse:hover {
   animation: none;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
   0% {
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
   }
   70% {
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
   }
   100% {
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
   }
 }

 @keyframes pulse {
   0% {
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(196,33,61, 0.85);
   }
   70% {
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
       box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
   }
   100% {
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
       box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
   }
 }
```

**html:**

```
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="alertingDashboardDropdown" href="#">Alerts Dashboard
                    <span class="label {{alertCount.totalOpenAlertsLabelClass}} dropdown-subscript-white pull-right">{{alertCount.totalOpenAlerts}}</span>
                </a>
.
.
```

`{{alertCount.totalOpenAlertsLabelClass}}` basically returns "label-primary pulse"

Comment: Try to animate an element containing a box-shadow, not the box-shadow property itself. Relevant article: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because you are using `box-shadow` which is not very good for animations because it will trigger a repaint.

You can [check here](https://csstriggers.com/) what properties trigger layout, paint and composite changes.

The best ones are `opacity` and `transform`, maybe you can change your animation to use those.

**EDIT:** Created 2 jsfiddle, one with [box-shadow](https://jsfiddle.net/wrzn1z6j/) and another one with [transform](https://jsfiddle.net/aofejxbg/). I have edited your code but you can check the performance, study it, understand the changes and adapt it to your needs.

**How I did it:**

Added a `:before` pseudo-element that will have the animation running under the number. `will-change: transform;` tells the browser that the element's transform will change and the browser optimizes it.

```css
.pulse {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px; 
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #cca92c;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.pulse:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cca92c;
  border-radius: 100%; 
  z-index: -1;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite; 
  will-change: transform;
}

.pulse:hover:before {
  animation: none;
}

 @keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
 }
```

```html
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="alertingDashboardDropdown" href="#">
  <span>Alerts Dashboard</span>
  <span class="pulse">5</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I really don't have too much idea about the css, let alone working with the animations. I shall take a look

Comment: @blueren Added an example with transform

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appriciate the quick resolution. Might I advice you to keep the code posted on this answer as well, should the jsfiddle link go dead in the future.

Comment: Done, added the `transform` code because I think that's the important one

Comment: So strange. I'm able to see it works in jsfiddle and in so. But when I put the same into my meteor project. It does not animate. I only get the yellow circle.

Comment: Maybe there is another style overriding the `.pulse:before`, try removing class by class until it works or the `pulse` is the only class left on the element